# Linear Algebra - Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over ℂ . Show that any linear transformation T:V→V has at least one eigenvalue λ and an associated eigenvector v.**

So I'm working through sample questions for an upcoming exam and I came across this. I'm not quite sure how to approach it as I'm not well accustomed to answering proof type questions as this module is an elective in my course (I am a physics student). I think I have to use q(λ) = det (λI - T) somewhere but I'm unsure in what way. Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ .Consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$ .Any polynomial over $\mathbb C$  has  a root in  $\mathbb C$

Comment: Will I just say A is any nxn matrix? Like can I say its a 2x2 matrix and find its eigenvalues in terms of a,b,c,d?

Comment: @teme92 It has to be arbitrary from the assumptions in the question: you're working with an arbitrary finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (which can be treated as just $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n$). At the end of the day the characteristic polynomial is a polynomial, so it has a root, so there is a $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, so this has a nontrivial solution, so there is an eigenvector.

Comment: So would what you said be a sufficient answer for a proof? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Yes, isn't it convincing for you